# document.domain is empty string for localhost, can't change it or access iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am opening some html documents from my local drive in an iframe, from what I've seen, their document.domain should be "localhost", however it is "". I get the error "Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame." when accessing my iframes, which is supposed to be fixed by setting the domain the same in the documents, but I am unable the change the domain because it is the empty string... not sure how to fix this so I can gain access to my iframes.

Comment: The domain will only be `localhost` if you're opening it from a local webserver, not from a file.

Comment: I did not get it to work with document.URL (same errors). I guess the postmessage solution is easier :/